# My injected <script> runs after the target-page's javascript, despite using run_at: document_start?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am having some problem with the order of javascript execution when I use the content script to inject some javascript into the HTML page:

This is my HTML page I use to test, ***test.html***:

```
<html><head>    
<title>Test Page</title></head>
  <body>
    <script>
      console.log("In page");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the javascript I use to inject additional code into HTML page, ***injector.js***:

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL("inject.js");
document.documentElement.appendChild(s);
console.log("Inject finished");
```

And this is the content of injected script, ***inject.js***:

```
console.log("Inside inject.js");
```

And finally, this is my ***manifest.json***:

```
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "inject.js"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["/injector.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ]
```

Now, when I open up the *test.html*, this is what I got in my console:

```
Inject finished
In page
Inside inject.js
```

My question is, why is `In page` printed out before `Inside inject.js`? Isn't `inject.js` supposed to be run first since I set the `run_at` to `document_start`?

If this is by design, is there any way I can make sure that the content inside inject.js is executed before the script inside the HTML page **while not changing anything inside the HTML page**?

Setting the `async` attribute to `false` before `appendChild` doesn't seem to work since it is used for the ordering between the external scripts, not between external scripts and in-page script.

BTW, I am testing this on Chrome 27.0.1453.9

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Injected scripts, with `src` attributes are executed asynchronously in Chrome.
Consider this HTML file:

```html
<html><head>
    <title>Chrome early script inject, Test Page</title>
    <script>
        var s = document.createElement ("script");
        s.src = "localInject1.js";
        document.documentElement.appendChild (s);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<p>See the console.</p>
<script src="localInject2.js"></script>
<script> console.log("In page: ", new Date().getTime()); </script>
</body>
</html>
```

where ***localInject1.js*** is just:

```
console.log("In page's script 1: ", new Date().getTime());
```

and ***localInject2.js*** is:

```
console.log("In page's script 2: ", new Date().getTime());
```

Nominally, the console should show:

```
In page's script 1:   ...
In page's script 2:   ...
In page:   ...
```

But frequently, and especially on cache-less reloads, you'll see:

```
In page's script 2:   ...
In page:   ...
In page's script 1:   ...
```

Setting `s.async = false;` makes no difference.

---

I'm not sure if this is a bug or not.  Firefox also gets the scripts out of order, but seems more consistent about it.  There don't seem to be [any relevant Chrome bugs](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list?can=1&q=injected%20javascript&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Modified&x=m&y=releaseblock&cells=tiles), and the specs are unclear to me.

---

### Work around:

Scripts with code set by `textContent`, rather than a file linked by `src`, execute immediately as you would expect.
For example, if you changed ***injector.js*** to:

```
var s = document.createElement ("script");
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL ("inject.js");
document.documentElement.appendChild (s);

var s = document.createElement ('script');
s.textContent = 'console.log ("Text runs correctly!", new Date().getTime() );';
document.documentElement.appendChild (s);

console.log("Inject finished", new Date().getTime() );
```

you would see:

```
Text runs correctly! ...
Inject finished ...
In page
Inside inject.js
```

Admittedly this can be a pain in a content script, but it may be all you can do (in Chrome) until this issue is resolved by the W3C and browser vendors.

Comment: I think the only problem of the work around solution is that it is difficult to write code in a string. Using a script to generate it may be help. I wrote one here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713181/a-issue-when-inject-a-javascript-code-that-overrides-the-one-existing-in-dom

Comment: Actually, @Hui.Li, getting code to a string is fairly easy in javascript.  Merely wrap it in a function, EG: `function foo() { /*Your code goes here*/ }`, then use `.toString()` on the function.  EG: `s.textContent = '('+foo.toString ()+')();'`.

Comment: @BrockAdams Is there a way to do some very basic message passing before execution of this script at document_start?

Comment: @SrikanthRayabhagi, you need to ask a new question with details about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript `script` tags are not blocking the execution (thankfully!). If you'd like to get the kind of functionality you want (lazy-loading), you'll need to do something like the following:

```
function loadScript(scriptName, callback) {
   var sTag = document.createElement("script");
   sTag.src = scriptName;
   sTag.onreadystatechange = sTag.onload = function() {
    var state = s.readyState;

    if (!state || /loaded|complete/.test(state)) {
        callback();
    }
  };
 }
```

This will fire a callback function when the script tag is loaded. From there, load everything and make sure that every callback is processed, then fire your page-load events in the sanity of mind that you have every library you need.

Answer (score 0):

When you inject javascript onto the page like that, it comes in asynchronously. When you actually have the `<script>` tag in there from the beginning, it will be synchronous and run in the correct order.

Kind of a hassle, but since it's asynchronous, your code will continue to execute while the other script file is being loaded.

In order to know when the script is complete, you have to handle the event for the script - easiest way is using jQuery's `getScript` function, which provides you a callback argument.

Comment: Hi, I believe you meant to use getScript inside the html page right? I added one more annoyance to my question: "...while not changing anything inside the html page?". Any idea?

Comment: Without changing the HTML, I don't see how - in order to get a script to run prior to the script that's there, you'd have to put a script tag in before the one on the page. But there's a lot of funky stuff you can do with those extensions, so maybe there's just something I haven't heard of.

Answer (score 0):

There are entire libraries dedicated to achieving what you are trying to do, as each browser seems to add its own share of bugs. Have a look at something like HeadJS, or if already using jQuery what joe said.

Comment: Neither Joe's answer, nor HeadJS apply in the context of this *Chrome extension* problem.  The OP can't control the source of the target page (his SSCCE, sample HTML is just to illustrate the nature of the problem in a concise way).