# Will <script> tags be blocking and execute one after another?

Tags: javascript

In the code below, will `bar.js` only run after `foo.js` had loaded and run?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <script src='foo.js'></script>
  <script src='bar.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Assuming I don't use `async` or `deferred`, I think so. However, [this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730869/my-injected-script-runs-after-the-target-pages-javascript-despite-using-run) insists that scripts that programmatically set `src` do not block - does that not apply to literally inserted `<script>` tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this page (https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/even-faster-web/9780596803773/ch04.html), external .js files loaded with src will indeed be run sequentially, and this is intended behavior.  Older browsers will download the external files sequentially, then run them sequentially, while newer browsers will download them in parallel (simultaneously), but still run them sequentially.  According to the answers on this page ([Implications of multiple <script> tags in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659409/implications-of-multiple-script-tags-in-html)), inline  tags also run sequentially.  The first web site linked shows several ways to get multiple external scripts to run simultaneously, however, if that is your desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't apply.

'script' tags in HTML code always block.

Reference: High Performance Javascript, 1. -> Script Positioning